# I can't load a data file, always failure to open it

Tags: c++, raytracing

I'm actually writing a raytracer, and I have a function which load the .off. I am working with xcode, and I have in the same folder my .h .cpp and my .off. this is the beginning of my function:

```
void Mesh::loadOFF (const std::string & filename) {
   clear ();
   ifstream input (filename.c_str ());
   if (!input)
      throw Exception ("Failing opening the file.");
```

And the calling is:

```
Mesh sphereMesh;
sphereMesh.loadOFF ("sphere.off");
```

I don't understand what it's always failing opening if my .off and the files are in the same folder. Could someone help me?

Comment: Make sure the working directory is set to the correct location. For example, you might want to run the code from the command line: `cd` to the correct directory and run it with `./your-program-name-goes-here`.

Comment: Is the executable created in the same folder as your `h` and `cpp` files?

Comment: Hello, thanks for you response, but I don't have the ./your-program-name-goes-here part in the folder

Comment: I actually am new to xcode so I don't know where the executable is :s

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode programs are apparently build in a somewhat odd location. It seems they are normally located at

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project-specific-directory>/Products/<config>
```

That is, you could `cd` to the directory where your file is and then run

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project-specific-directory>/Products/Debug/<program>
```

It seems the general recommendation is *not* to depend on relative directories when trying to open existing files. If you want to open file a relative to the current directory, you should probably set the directory correspondingly using the `chdir()` system call in you program:

```
int main() {
    chdir("/path-to-the-directory-with-your-file/");
    // ...
}
```